# Which one of the following..., Single or Multiple possible answers

Tags: meaning, questions

In a MCQ I was surprised to see that there were multiple correct answers to the following question:

> [...] Which one of the following entities can perform this action?

I thought that "which one" implied that there was only one possible solution.
Is this assumption correct (implying the question is malformed) or does the formulation "which one of the following ..." means one or more ?

Thanks.

Update: it was a MCQ from a mock exam that the teacher gave us to practice, some of the other exercises had multiple correct answers.
I was surprised to learn from the provided exam solutions that this particular question had more than one correct answer, given the wording used. There was no error in the question, only the question was asked that way and there were multiple correct answers that we had to mark (1 point if all correct answers were marked, 0 point otherwise).

Comment: Asking for one correct answer when there are several should, in my opinion, not be done using 'Which one'. I agree that the default (probably the sole) meaning here entails that just one answer is correct. 'Name one of the following ...' works (but may still worry people correctly taught to normally give full answers). 'Several of the following entities can perform this action. Name one that can.' is how I'd ask this.

Comment: Since multiple choice questions normally have one answer, you should explain what kind of multiple choice question it is, and how you know it has multiple answers - was it intended to do so, or did the teacher subsequently find that there was an error in the question and multiple answers could be correct? If the latter, there's your answer; otherwise "Which of the following..." might be better, although it would still depend on what exact answer was expected (select one, or choose all).

Comment: If there are multiple correct choices, but you only have to pick one of them, I think it's acceptable, but confusing. If you were expected to pick all the correct choices, it should say "Which ones".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because MCQs are an abomination, and SE English Language and Usage does not exist to discuss language of its perpetrators.

Comment: Not sure why this received 2 downvotes and then closed ? I provided more context as @StuartF asked

Comment: Why @EdwinAshworth answered using a comment ? I would have marked their response as the correct answer.

Comment: I guess because Edwin realized this question was going to get (or needed to be) closed. "Which" implies one of the answers, so the question was badly phrased considering the expected outcome, but that's more of a logic issue than a grammatical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that the grading required you to identify all the correct choices, the question is poorly worded. Your intuition is correct: "which one" implies that only one choice should be selected. They should have written "which ones" to indicate that you can and *must* choose all the correct choices.